# Boundary vs. Boundary??

Tags: general-topology, geometry

I was reading from a text earlier and the author made the statement:

> "For a closed surface (that is, the boundary of a solid region)"

and although it was not incredibly important for what I was reading about I wanted to make sure I knew precisely what types of objects they were referring to, I looked up *closed surface* and wiki says:

> "A closed surface is a surface that is compact and without boundary.
>   Example: Sphere"

I accepted this example as it matched up with what my text said, the boundary of a solid region and obviously the sphere is the boundary of the ball... but what is wiki saying regarding "must be compact **without boundary?"**. From my knowledge of elementary (emphasis on elementary) topology I take the sphere to be essentially... entirely boundary points. From a bit more wiki hunting it seems like they are using "without boundary" to mean no edge?

My question is then.. would a bounded cone not suffice as a "closed surface" then?

Or a cube in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with no interior?

Should I take closed surface to mean compact with no "edge"?

Comment: The first statement is that a closed surface is the boundary of a 3D region. The second is that a closed surface has no (1D) boundary. You are correct that a cone has boundary and hence is not a closed surface.

Comment: One is talking about topological boundary. Another is talking about manifold boundary. The beginning example for the difference between two concepts is to consider a surface of a hemisphere sitting in $\mathbb{R}^3$: The topological boundary consists of entire of it. The manifold boundary consists of the equator.

Comment: That's confusing isn't it.  The closed surface is a boundary *of something else* and has no boundary *itself*.  The bounded cone has a boudary-- a circle-- and the circle itself is a closed surface (in one less dimension) with no boundary of its own.  The surface of a 3 d cube is the boundary of a 3d solid but as a 2d surface has no boundary.

Comment: Thank you to all three of you. I see now, I was just getting confused since the same word was popping up one in the context of topology and one in the context of manifolds. No exposure to manifolds yet myself so wasn't keen on the terminology. And @fleablood one last question, when you said the 3d cube as a 2d surface.. would this be its projection into one less dimension? So it would be the square were saying has no boundary?

Comment: No, I meant the surface of the cube is a 2d surface.  It's topologically equivalent to the sphere.  It's a finite "bent" bounded but boundary less 2d surface.  And no, the squares have boundary/edges but the six squares are glued together into a sphere so they don't count.  Basically a solid in n-D will have a boundary.  That boundary will be an (n-1) D surface without a boundary.  A solid sphere has S_2 as its boundary.  S_2 is consider 2D.  A disk is 2D but a circle is 1-D.  Etc.  A solid sphere is 3 d but an empty shere is 2D. It's curved in 3d but locally it only has 2 dimensions.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry I am having such an amateur hour over here! But thank you, the more I look into all of this the less confusing it is getting. @fleablood